# Move div rather than Remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
        var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
        if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
            $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                /* STOP event bubbling */
                e.stopPropagation();    
            }).click(function () {
                if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                        opacity: 0    
                    },function () {
                        $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                            iNettuts.savePreferences();
                        });
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
        }
```

Basically right now this code when 'close' is clicked it removes the content completely. What i would rather do is move it to a different div. I was reading about prependTo. I thought this would be as simple as changing:

```
$(this).remove();
```

To:

```
$(this).prependTo('.dock');
```

But doesn't seem to be that simple. This just removes it still. [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/u64XXAQ5)

Comment: Actually, it should be that simple ?

Comment: Yup. appendTo should work too

Comment: Yes, in "moving" an element it *will* be "removed" from the current location when added to the new parent node: a DOM node can only exist *at one location at a time*. Perhaps you want to duplicate or clone it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will preserve the original element:

```
$('yourElement').clone().appendTo('whereverYouWant');
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uyunop/4/edit)**

---

If you want to remove it from it's original place:

```
$('yourElement').appendTo('whereverYouWant');
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uyunop/2/edit)**

Same as:

```
$('yourElement').remove().clone().appendTo('whereverYouWant');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), because remove also removes all element's references.

```
    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
        $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            /* STOP event bubbling */
            e.stopPropagation();    
        }).click(function () {
            if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                    opacity: 0    
                },function () {
                    $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                        $(this).detach().prependTo('.dock');
                        iNettuts.savePreferences();
                    });
                });
            }
            return false;
        }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this is wrong! Prepending and appending elements will effectivly move them. `detach()` is for detaching elements for a given time, and then reappending them, unlike `remove()` which completely removes an element so that it can't be appended back in and keep handlers etc. For just moving an element, detach is useless and uneccessary, and does nothing worth noting when followed by `prependTo()`.

Comment: detach is the only you need to preserve any event, prop and data, before ~pendTo. @adeneo remove is really to be meant as becoming deleted... or respawned! you can move and re-insert also remove'ds
| in fact, remove returns you the current 'default' html representation, without javaScript object model, without DOMEvents, only the 'html' element object.